# header row extraction and insertion in different tables using sql studio

Tags: mysql

I would like to extract the row header from a table and insert it in another table with the same number of columns and data type, how can i do it in sql studio without having to retype the whole headers again ?
[header row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDPdr.png)

[second table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8quzZ.png)

Comment: that's not a "row header" sql tables don't have headers. they have a structure, which is what's used to generate that display-time header. if you want to clone the structure, then do something like `create table foo like bar`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use create table like

```
 CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;
```

this create an empty table with the same column name of the orig_tbl

if you need to change the column name  you can use alter table

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name  CHANGE `Column 0`  `Extension Field 1` ;
```

Comment: I have already imported my second table and it has all the data in it already, i am just missing the headers.

Comment: the header of  a database table are the column name  .. you can,t import a  tablle without (at least ) a column  name  ... please explain better what do you mean ..

Comment: I have update the answer  assuming you need to change the column name

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to do  for all column names without having to type them just by extracting them from previous table.

Comment: Unfortunately not ..but with a good editor is to change only the numbers